# app crease after use flutter 1.17.1 in android in reales mode

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i'm useing

- firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
- cloud_firestore: ^0.13.6
- firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16

and i use flutter 1.17.1
and app working fine in debug mode
but after using reales mode
app crashing when use cloud_firestore code in flutter
any help

this is my android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is my android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            //minifyEnabled false            
        }
        /*debug{
            minifyEnabled false
        }*/
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

any help to make app not crash

Answer (score 0):

In your Android manifest file add internet permission if its not already added.

By default the permission is not added but it works in debug mode, before release you have to add. 
[android developers](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting)

if it still crashes check the logs in Android studio and post here.

Hope this helps.

There are deployment related steps on [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) check if you have missed something.

Comment: app crash without print any thing

Comment: Check if the internet permission if present in your android manifest file.

Comment: i added this
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: i think it's something in cloud_firestore package it make app crash

Comment: because app not crash when use flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.9

Comment: and app crash when i run flutter run --release in ios in ipad

Comment: Try changing the classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

Comment: In firebase console you might need to make changes for production, initial it is enabled in test mode.

Comment: i delete old project and add new one with production mode for cloud firestore database and still app crash and i change the classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3' and still app crash

Comment: Sorry cant think of anything else. Check the guide once https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Comment: @AhmedTaha i have mentioned your problem on a github issue. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58015

Comment: after i update macos to macos catalina 10.15.5 and xcode to xcode 11.5 it's work good no crash

Answer (score 0):

when i use flutter run --profile
it gives me this error
E/Dart    ( 8221): ../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/code_descriptors.cc: 838: error: expected: current_pc_offset <= pc_offset
E/DartVM  ( 8221): version=2.8.2 (stable) (Mon May 11 15:06:42 2020 +0200) on "android_arm64"
E/DartVM  ( 8221): pid=8221, thread=8261, isolate=main(0x7afdc3ba00)
E/DartVM  ( 8221): isolate_instructions=7aee24b000, vm_instructions=7aee246000
E/DartVM  ( 8221):   pc 0x0000007af05f1588 fp 0x0000007aef7f48f0 /data/app/com.jaadara.lena-BUF-VImPFNKCbnkB4r4Trw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so+0xbd7588
E/DartVM  ( 8221): -- End of DumpStackTrace
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [exit     : sp(0) fp(0x7aef7f4bd8) pc(0)]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-stub : sp(0x7aef7f4be8) fp(0x7aef7f4be8) pc(0x7aee86df58)]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4bf8) fp(0x7aef7f4c30) pc(0x7aee8130ec) *package:flutter/src/painting/text_span.dart_TextSpan_compareTo ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4c40) fp(0x7aef7f4c58) pc(0x7aee35a15c) *package:flutter/src/rendering/paragraph.dart_RenderParagraph_set_text ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4c68) fp(0x7aef7f4c78) pc(0x7aee760df8) *package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart_RichText_updateRenderObject ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4c88) fp(0x7aef7f4ca8) pc(0x7aee7adb60) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_RenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4cb8) fp(0x7aef7f4cd8) pc(0x7aee7adc78) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_MultiChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4ce8) fp(0x7aef7f4d00) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4d10) fp(0x7aef7f4e00) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4e10) fp(0x7aef7f4e18) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4e28) fp(0x7aef7f4e30) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4e40) fp(0x7aef7f4e58) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4e68) fp(0x7aef7f4e98) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4ea8) fp(0x7aef7f4ec0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4ed0) fp(0x7aef7f4fc0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4fd0) fp(0x7aef7f4fd8) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f4fe8) fp(0x7aef7f4ff0) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5000) fp(0x7aef7f5018) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5028) fp(0x7aef7f5118) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5128) fp(0x7aef7f5130) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5140) fp(0x7aef7f5168) pc(0x7aee7af850) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ProxyElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5178) fp(0x7aef7f5190) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f51a0) fp(0x7aef7f5258) pc(0x7aee418644) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_RenderObjectElement_updateChildren ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5268) fp(0x7aef7f5298) pc(0x7aee7aded8) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_MultiChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f52a8) fp(0x7aef7f52c0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f52d0) fp(0x7aef7f5300) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5310) fp(0x7aef7f5328) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5338) fp(0x7aef7f5428) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5438) fp(0x7aef7f5440) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5450) fp(0x7aef7f5458) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5468) fp(0x7aef7f5480) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5490) fp(0x7aef7f54c0) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f54d0) fp(0x7aef7f54e8) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f54f8) fp(0x7aef7f55e8) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f55f8) fp(0x7aef7f5600) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5610) fp(0x7aef7f5618) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5628) fp(0x7aef7f5680) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5690) fp(0x7aef7f56a8) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f56b8) fp(0x7aef7f57a8) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f57b8) fp(0x7aef7f57c0) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f57d0) fp(0x7aef7f57d8) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f57e8) fp(0x7aef7f5800) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5810) fp(0x7aef7f5900) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5910) fp(0x7aef7f5918) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5928) fp(0x7aef7f5930) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5940) fp(0x7aef7f5958) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5968) fp(0x7aef7f5998) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f59a8) fp(0x7aef7f59c0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f59d0) fp(0x7aef7f5ac0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5ad0) fp(0x7aef7f5ad8) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5ae8) fp(0x7aef7f5af0) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5b00) fp(0x7aef7f5b58) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5b68) fp(0x7aef7f5b80) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5b90) fp(0x7aef7f5bc0) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5bd0) fp(0x7aef7f5be8) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5bf8) fp(0x7aef7f5c28) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5c38) fp(0x7aef7f5c50) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5c60) fp(0x7aef7f5d50) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5d60) fp(0x7aef7f5d68) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5d78) fp(0x7aef7f5d80) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5d90) fp(0x7aef7f5de8) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5df8) fp(0x7aef7f5e10) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5e20) fp(0x7aef7f5e50) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5e60) fp(0x7aef7f5e78) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5e88) fp(0x7aef7f5eb8) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5ec8) fp(0x7aef7f5ee0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5ef0) fp(0x7aef7f5fe0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f5ff0) fp(0x7aef7f5ff8) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6008) fp(0x7aef7f6010) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6020) fp(0x7aef7f6038) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6048) fp(0x7aef7f6138) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6148) fp(0x7aef7f6150) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6160) fp(0x7aef7f6188) pc(0x7aee7af850) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ProxyElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6198) fp(0x7aef7f61b0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f61c0) fp(0x7aef7f62b0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f62c0) fp(0x7aef7f62c8) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f62d8) fp(0x7aef7f62e0) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f62f0) fp(0x7aef7f6348) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6358) fp(0x7aef7f6370) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6380) fp(0x7aef7f6470) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6480) fp(0x7aef7f6488) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6498) fp(0x7aef7f64a0) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f64b0) fp(0x7aef7f64c8) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f64d8) fp(0x7aef7f6518) pc(0x7aee7c49c4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart_SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6528) fp(0x7aef7f6570) pc(0x7aee90becc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart_SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement_performRebuild_processElement ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6580) fp(0x7aef7f65a0) pc(0x7aee581fec) *dart:core_Iterable_forEach ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f65b0) fp(0x7aef7f6688) pc(0x7aee7bb8f8) *package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart_SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6698) fp(0x7aef7f66b8) pc(0x7aee7ae1c0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart_SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f66c8) fp(0x7aef7f66e0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f66f0) fp(0x7aef7f67e0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f67f0) fp(0x7aef7f67f8) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6808) fp(0x7aef7f6830) pc(0x7aee7af850) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ProxyElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6840) fp(0x7aef7f6858) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6868) fp(0x7aef7f6898) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f68a8) fp(0x7aef7f68c0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f68d0) fp(0x7aef7f6988) pc(0x7aee418644) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_RenderObjectElement_updateChildren ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6998) fp(0x7aef7f69c8) pc(0x7aee7aded8) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_MultiChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f69d8) fp(0x7aef7f69f0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6a00) fp(0x7aef7f6a30) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6a40) fp(0x7aef7f6a58) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6a68) fp(0x7aef7f6a98) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6aa8) fp(0x7aef7f6ac0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6ad0) fp(0x7aef7f6b00) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6b10) fp(0x7aef7f6b28) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6b38) fp(0x7aef7f6c28) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6c38) fp(0x7aef7f6c40) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6c50) fp(0x7aef7f6c58) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6c68) fp(0x7aef7f6c80) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6c90) fp(0x7aef7f6cc0) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6cd0) fp(0x7aef7f6ce8) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6cf8) fp(0x7aef7f6de8) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6df8) fp(0x7aef7f6e00) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6e10) fp(0x7aef7f6e18) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6e28) fp(0x7aef7f6e80) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6e90) fp(0x7aef7f6ea8) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6eb8) fp(0x7aef7f6ee8) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6ef8) fp(0x7aef7f6f10) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f6f20) fp(0x7aef7f7010) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7020) fp(0x7aef7f7028) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7038) fp(0x7aef7f7040) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7050) fp(0x7aef7f7068) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7078) fp(0x7aef7f7168) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7178) fp(0x7aef7f7180) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7190) fp(0x7aef7f71b8) pc(0x7aee7af850) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ProxyElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f71c8) fp(0x7aef7f71e0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f71f0) fp(0x7aef7f7220) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7230) fp(0x7aef7f7248) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7258) fp(0x7aef7f7288) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7298) fp(0x7aef7f72b0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f72c0) fp(0x7aef7f72f0) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7300) fp(0x7aef7f7318) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7328) fp(0x7aef7f7358) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7368) fp(0x7aef7f7380) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7390) fp(0x7aef7f7480) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7490) fp(0x7aef7f7498) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f74a8) fp(0x7aef7f74b0) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f74c0) fp(0x7aef7f74d8) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f74e8) fp(0x7aef7f75d8) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f75e8) fp(0x7aef7f75f0) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7600) fp(0x7aef7f7608) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7618) fp(0x7aef7f7670) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7680) fp(0x7aef7f7698) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f76a8) fp(0x7aef7f7798) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f77a8) fp(0x7aef7f77b0) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f77c0) fp(0x7aef7f77c8) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f77d8) fp(0x7aef7f7830) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7840) fp(0x7aef7f7858) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7868) fp(0x7aef7f7958) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7968) fp(0x7aef7f7970) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7980) fp(0x7aef7f7988) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7998) fp(0x7aef7f79b0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f79c0) fp(0x7aef7f7ab0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]

Answer (score 0):

and left error 
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7da8) fp(0x7aef7f7db0) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7dc0) fp(0x7aef7f7e18) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7e28) fp(0x7aef7f7e40) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7e50) fp(0x7aef7f7f40) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7f50) fp(0x7aef7f7f58) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7f68) fp(0x7aef7f7f70) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7f80) fp(0x7aef7f7fd8) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f7fe8) fp(0x7aef7f8000) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8010) fp(0x7aef7f8040) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8050) fp(0x7aef7f8068) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8078) fp(0x7aef7f80a8) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f80b8) fp(0x7aef7f80d0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f80e0) fp(0x7aef7f81d0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f81e0) fp(0x7aef7f81e8) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f81f8) fp(0x7aef7f8200) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8210) fp(0x7aef7f8228) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8238) fp(0x7aef7f8268) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8278) fp(0x7aef7f8290) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f82a0) fp(0x7aef7f8390) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f83a0) fp(0x7aef7f83a8) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f83b8) fp(0x7aef7f83c0) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f83d0) fp(0x7aef7f8428) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8438) fp(0x7aef7f8450) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8460) fp(0x7aef7f8490) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f84a0) fp(0x7aef7f84b8) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f84c8) fp(0x7aef7f84f8) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8508) fp(0x7aef7f8520) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8530) fp(0x7aef7f8620) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8630) fp(0x7aef7f8638) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8648) fp(0x7aef7f8650) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8660) fp(0x7aef7f86b8) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f86c8) fp(0x7aef7f86e0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f86f0) fp(0x7aef7f8720) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]

E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8730) fp(0x7aef7f8748) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8758) fp(0x7aef7f8788) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8798) fp(0x7aef7f87b0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f87c0) fp(0x7aef7f88b0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f88c0) fp(0x7aef7f88c8) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f88d8) fp(0x7aef7f88e0) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f88f0) fp(0x7aef7f8908) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8918) fp(0x7aef7f8a08) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8a18) fp(0x7aef7f8a20) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8a30) fp(0x7aef7f8a58) pc(0x7aee7af850) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ProxyElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8a68) fp(0x7aef7f8a80) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8a90) fp(0x7aef7f8b80) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8b90) fp(0x7aef7f8b98) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8ba8) fp(0x7aef7f8bb0) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8bc0) fp(0x7aef7f8c18) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8c28) fp(0x7aef7f8c40) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8c50) fp(0x7aef7f8d40) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8d50) fp(0x7aef7f8d58) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8d68) fp(0x7aef7f8d70) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8d80) fp(0x7aef7f8d98) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8da8) fp(0x7aef7f8de8) pc(0x7aee7c49c4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart_SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8df8) fp(0x7aef7f8e40) pc(0x7aee90becc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart_SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement_performRebuild_processElement ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8e50) fp(0x7aef7f8e70) pc(0x7aee581fec) *dart:core_Iterable_forEach ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8e80) fp(0x7aef7f8f58) pc(0x7aee7bb8f8) *package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart_SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8f68) fp(0x7aef7f8f88) pc(0x7aee7ae1c0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart_SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8f98) fp(0x7aef7f8fb0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f8fc0) fp(0x7aef7f8ff0) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9000) fp(0x7aef7f9018) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9028) fp(0x7aef7f90e0) pc(0x7aee418644) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_RenderObjectElement_updateChildren ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f90f0) fp(0x7aef7f9120) pc(0x7aee7aded8) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_MultiChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9130) fp(0x7aef7f9140) pc(0x7aee7adbe8) *package:flutter/src/widgets/viewport.dart__ViewportElement@728166613_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9150) fp(0x7aef7f9168) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9178) fp(0x7aef7f91a8) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f91b8) fp(0x7aef7f91d0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f91e0) fp(0x7aef7f9210) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9220) fp(0x7aef7f9238) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9248) fp(0x7aef7f9278) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9288) fp(0x7aef7f92a0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f92b0) fp(0x7aef7f93a0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f93b0) fp(0x7aef7f93b8) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f93c8) fp(0x7aef7f93d0) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f93e0) fp(0x7aef7f93f8) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9408) fp(0x7aef7f9438) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9448) fp(0x7aef7f9460) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9470) fp(0x7aef7f9560) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9570) fp(0x7aef7f9578) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9588) fp(0x7aef7f9590) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f95a0) fp(0x7aef7f95f8) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9608) fp(0x7aef7f9620) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9630) fp(0x7aef7f9660) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9670) fp(0x7aef7f9688) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9698) fp(0x7aef7f9788) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9798) fp(0x7aef7f97a0) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f97b0) fp(0x7aef7f97b8) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f97c8) fp(0x7aef7f97e0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f97f0) fp(0x7aef7f98e0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f98f0) fp(0x7aef7f98f8) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9908) fp(0x7aef7f9930) pc(0x7aee7af850) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ProxyElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9940) fp(0x7aef7f9958) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9968) fp(0x7aef7f9998) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f99a8) fp(0x7aef7f99c0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f99d0) fp(0x7aef7f9a00) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9a10) fp(0x7aef7f9a28) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9a38) fp(0x7aef7f9a68) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9a78) fp(0x7aef7f9a90) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9aa0) fp(0x7aef7f9ad0) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9ae0) fp(0x7aef7f9af8) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9b08) fp(0x7aef7f9bf8) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9c08) fp(0x7aef7f9c10) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9c20) fp(0x7aef7f9c28) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9c38) fp(0x7aef7f9c50) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9c60) fp(0x7aef7f9d50) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9d60) fp(0x7aef7f9d68) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9d78) fp(0x7aef7f9d80) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9d90) fp(0x7aef7f9de8) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9df8) fp(0x7aef7f9e10) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9e20) fp(0x7aef7f9f10) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9f20) fp(0x7aef7f9f28) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9f38) fp(0x7aef7f9f40) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9f50) fp(0x7aef7f9fa8) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9fb8) fp(0x7aef7f9fd0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7f9fe0) fp(0x7aef7fa0d0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fa0e0) fp(0x7aef7fa0e8) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fa0f8) fp(0x7aef7fa120) pc(0x7aee7af850) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ProxyElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fa130) fp(0x7aef7fa148) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fa158) fp(0x7aef7fa248) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb340) fp(0x7aef7fb348) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb370) fp(0x7aef7fb388) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb398) fp(0x7aef7fb450) pc(0x7aee418644) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_RenderObjectElement_updateChildren ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb460) fp(0x7aef7fb490) pc(0x7aee7aded8) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_MultiChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb4a0) fp(0x7aef7fb4b8) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb5c8) fp(0x7aef7fb5d0) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb5e0) fp(0x7aef7fb5e8) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb660) fp(0x7aef7fb678) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb688) fp(0x7aef7fb778) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb7e0) fp(0x7aef7fb8d0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb8e0) fp(0x7aef7fb8e8) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb8f8) fp(0x7aef7fb920) pc(0x7aee7af850) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ProxyElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb930) fp(0x7aef7fb948) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fb958) fp(0x7aef7fba48) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fba70) fp(0x7aef7fba98) pc(0x7aee7af850) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ProxyElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fbad0) fp(0x7aef7fbb88) pc(0x7aee418644) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_RenderObjectElement_updateChildren ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fbb98) fp(0x7aef7fbbc8) pc(0x7aee7aded8) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_MultiChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fbd18) fp(0x7aef7fbd20) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fbd30) fp(0x7aef7fbd88) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fbd98) fp(0x7aef7fbdb0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fbdc0) fp(0x7aef7fbeb0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fbec0) fp(0x7aef7fbec8) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fbed8) fp(0x7aef7fbf00) pc(0x7aee7af850) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ProxyElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fbf10) fp(0x7aef7fbf28) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fbf38) fp(0x7aef7fc028) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc038) fp(0x7aef7fc040) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc050) fp(0x7aef7fc058) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc068) fp(0x7aef7fc0c0) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc0d0) fp(0x7aef7fc0e8) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc0f8) fp(0x7aef7fc128) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc138) fp(0x7aef7fc150) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc160) fp(0x7aef7fc250) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc260) fp(0x7aef7fc268) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc278) fp(0x7aef7fc280) pc(0x7aee7aeb08) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatelessElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc290) fp(0x7aef7fc2a8) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc2b8) fp(0x7aef7fc2e8) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc2f8) fp(0x7aef7fc310) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc320) fp(0x7aef7fc410) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc420) fp(0x7aef7fc428) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc438) fp(0x7aef7fc440) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc450) fp(0x7aef7fc4a8) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc4b8) fp(0x7aef7fc4d0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc4e0) fp(0x7aef7fc5d0) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc5e0) fp(0x7aef7fc5e8) pc(0x7aee7bbcf0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc5f8) fp(0x7aef7fc600) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc610) fp(0x7aef7fc668) pc(0x7aee7aecb0) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_StatefulElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc678) fp(0x7aef7fc690) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc6a0) fp(0x7aef7fc790) pc(0x7aee7bc124) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ComponentElement_performRebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc7a0) fp(0x7aef7fc7a8) pc(0x7aee41b408) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_rebuild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc7b8) fp(0x7aef7fc7e0) pc(0x7aee7af850) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_ProxyElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fc7f0) fp(0x7aef7fc808) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fd4c8) fp(0x7aef7fd4e0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fd4f0) fp(0x7aef7fd520) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fd530) fp(0x7aef7fd548) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fd558) fp(0x7aef7fd588) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fd598) fp(0x7aef7fd5b0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fd5c0) fp(0x7aef7fd678) pc(0x7aee418644) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_RenderObjectElement_updateChildren ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fd688) fp(0x7aef7fd6b8) pc(0x7aee7aded8) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_MultiChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fd6c8) fp(0x7aef7fd6e0) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fd6f0) fp(0x7aef7fd720) pc(0x7aee7ad9d4) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_SingleChildRenderObjectElement_update ]
E/DartVM  ( 8221): [bare-dart : sp(0x7aef7fd730) fp(0x7aef7fd748) pc(0x7aee7c4cfc) *package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart_Element_updateChild ]
F/libc    ( 8221): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8261 (1.ui)

---

Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/LDN-L21B/HWLDN-Q:8.0.0/HUAWEILDN-L21/166(C185):user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 8221, tid: 8261, name: 1.ui  >>> com.jaadara.lena <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000002045  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
    x4   0000007aef7ff588  x5   0000007aef7ff588  x6   0000007aef7ff588  x7   7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
    x8   0000000000000083  x9   b30c0de37711a693  x10  0000007aef7ff588  x11  b30c0de37711a693
    x12  b30c0de37711a693  x13  0000000000000020  x14  0000007b1002e90c  x15  b30c0de37711a693
    x16  0000007b100e92d8  x17  0000007b1007ca38  x18  000000000000003d  x19  000000000000201d
    x20  0000000000002045  x21  0000007ad37ef858  x22  0000007aee813004  x23  0000000000000000
    x24  0000007aee8130ec  x25  0000007aef722000  x26  0000007afdc13c00  x27  0000007aea180040
    x28  0000000000000004  x29  0000007aef7f48f0  x30  0000007b10022394
    sp   0000007aef7f48b0  pc   0000007b1007ca40  pstate 0000000060000000
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0000000000078a40  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
    #01 pc 000000000001e390  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+88)
    #02 pc 0000000000a0b280  /data/app/com.jaadara.lena-BUF-VImPFNKCbnkB4r4Trw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x700000)
    #03 pc 0000000000b05190  /data/app/com.jaadara.lena-BUF-VImPFNKCbnkB4r4Trw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x700000)
    #04 pc 0000000000af9af0  /data/app/com.jaadara.lena-BUF-VImPFNKCbnkB4r4Trw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x700000)
    #05 pc 0000000000005588  /data/app/com.jaadara.lena-BUF-VImPFNKCbnkB4r4Trw==/lib/arm64/libapp.so (offset 0x2000) (_kDartVmSnapshotInstructions+13704)
Lost connection to device.